# Why can't a bind variable be used from ojdbc with Oracle JSON_ARRAY() in the presence of FORMAT JSON

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

In Oracle, the following query:

```sql
select
  json_arrayagg(
    json_array(
      (select json_arrayagg(json_array(1) format json) from dual) format json,
      2
    )
    format json
  )
from dual
```

Produces the following JSON document:

```
[[[[1]],2]]
```

When I try to run this query with bind variables from JDBC like this:

```java
try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
    """
    select
      json_arrayagg(
        json_array(
          (select json_arrayagg(json_array(?) format json) from dual) format json,
          ?
        )
        format json
      )
    from dual
    """
)) {
    s.setInt(1, 1);
    s.setInt(2, 2); // This fails

    try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
}
```

Then I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setIntInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4956)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setInt(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4947)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setInt(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:202)
    at org.jooq.testscripts.JDBC.main(JDBC.java:50)
```

I'm using these versions:

- Database: Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
- ojdbc: com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:21.5.0.0

Is this a bug? Can it be worked around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it used to be a bug in ojdbc. It no longer appears in version `23.3.0.23.09`. Workarounds for older ojdbc driver versions include:

#### Cast the bind variable

```java
try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
    """
    select
      json_arrayagg(
        json_array(
          (select json_arrayagg(json_array(?) format json) from dual) format json,
          cast(? as number) -- cast here
        )
        format json
      )
    from dual
    """
)) {
    s.setInt(1, 1);
    s.setInt(2, 2);

    try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
}
```

#### Remove the `FORMAT JSON` directive just before the bind parameter marker

```java
try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
    """
    select
      json_arrayagg(
        json_array(
          (select json_arrayagg(json_array(?) format json) from dual) /* no format json here */,
          ?
        )
        format json
      )
    from dual
    """
)) {
    s.setInt(1, 1);
    s.setInt(2, 2);

    try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
}
```

#### Using a dummy expression around the bind variable

```java
try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
    """
    select
      json_arrayagg(
        json_array(
          (select json_arrayagg(json_array(?) format json) from dual) format json,
          nvl(null, ?) -- Dummy expression here
        )
        format json
      )
    from dual
    """
)) {
    s.setInt(1, 1);
    s.setInt(2, 2);

    try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
}
```

#### Interleave a `null` value, and remove it again with `absent on null`

```java
try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
    """
    select
      json_arrayagg(
        json_array(
          (select json_arrayagg(json_array(?) format json) from dual) format json,
          null, -- This is ignored
          ?
          absent on null
        )
        format json
      )
    from dual
    """
)) {
    s.setInt(1, 1);
    s.setInt(2, 2);

    try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
}
```